# How to download/retrieve image/file from Firebase Storage in Xamarin.Forms C#?

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin.forms, firebase-storage

I'm using FirebaseStorage.Net NuGet Package in Xamarin.Forms, and I want to retrieve the uploaded image/file in my Firebase Storage. Bases on my researching, the below code should be working, but after I execute the code, my app shut down immediately.

```
  var webCl = new WebClient();
  byte[] imgBytes = webCl.DownloadData(//Url of the image in the Firebase Storage);
  var img = ImageSource.FromStream(() => new MemoryStream(imgBytes));
  ProfileImage.Source = img;
```

Comment: Have you tried adding any basic exception handling code to determine the specific cause of the crash?

Comment: first Start debug with Try catch block so you can find out reason for exception

Comment: Adding the exception stopped my app from crashing and also made my code works. Appreciated that Mr. Jason and Anant!